# Порядок потока селекторов в css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Каким образом здесь зависит порядок селекторов? Переход не работает если поставить класс перехода первым https://jsfiddle.net/7u5z943r/ Какая разница? Ведь браузер запоминает весь поток целиком.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('div').click(function(){
       $('.q').toggleClass('q1'); 
    }); 
    
});
```

```css
.q1{
    background: red;
}
.q{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q"></div>
```

Comment: CSS - Cascading Style Sheets

Answer (score 4):

Как раз таки, порядок определения стилей и является ключевым. *Свойства* стиля, написанного ниже(после), перекрывают *свойства* стиля написанного выше(до).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('div').click(function(){
       $('.q').toggleClass('q1'); 
    }); 
    
});
```

```css
.q{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.q1{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q"></div>
```

Comment: Простая каскадность получается?

Comment: @PeGaS, да, собссно, как и гласит название - _Каскадные_ таблицы стилей

Answer (score 1):

Как выше написали в данном случае решающее значение имеет порядок, оно и понятно, браузеру же нужно какой-то один стиль выбрать, но для такой задачи еще можно указать стиль для элемента, который имеет оба класса `.q.q1`, тогда определяющим будет этот стиль, а не порядок.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('div').click(function(){
       $('.q').toggleClass('q1'); 
    }); 
    
});
```

```css
.q.q1{
    background: red;
}
.q{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q"></div>
```